# how to calculate sum of total key in same array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i need to calculate the total key within the following array that contains 4 different sub arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [total] => 4.2
            [sku] => 4321
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [total] => 2
            [sku] => 2456
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [total] => 3
            [sku] => 2245
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1.5
            [sku] => 2674
        )

)
```

i was calculating it using mysql directly but i prefer to use php

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(CAST(IFNULL(total,0) AS DECIMAL(10,2))) FROM trans WHERE trans.userid = :userid";
```

so total has to be in the same format as from the query

> 10.70

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop over the array, adding up as you go, and then formatting with `number_format()`, or use `array_column()` to extract the 'total', and use `array_sum()` to add them, and again, using `number_format()` or `sprintf()` to format them.

```
echo number_format(array_sum(array_column($array, 'total')), 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this:-

```
  $array = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [total] => 4.2
                [sku] => 4321
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [total] => 2
                [sku] => 2456
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [total] => 3
                [sku] => 2245
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [total] => 1.5
                [sku] => 2674
            )

    );
   $total = 0;

   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $total += $value['total'];
   }

   print_r($total);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate your array and sum all values like:

```php
<?php 
$array = array(
    array(
    'total' => 4.2,
    'sku' => 4321
    ),
    array(
    'total' => 2,
    'sku' => 2456
    ),
    array(
    'total' => 3,
    'sku' => 2245
    ),
    array(
    'total' => 1.5,
    'sku' => 2674
    ),
);


$result = array('total' => 0,'sku' => 0);
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $result['total'] += $value['total'];
    $result['sku'] += $value['sku'];
}
var_dump($result);
```

Result: array(2) { ["total"]=> float(10.7) ["sku"]=> int(11696) }

for single total sum output:

```
echo $result['total'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with `array_walk_recursive()` like this https://eval.in/875555

```
$input = [your_2d_array_goes_here];
$final = array();    
array_walk_recursive($input, function($item, $key) use (&$final){
    $final[$key] = isset($final[$key]) ?  $item + $final[$key] : $item;
});

print '<pre>';
print_r($final);
print '</pre>';
print $final['total'];
?>
```